# Multi replace with nodes

Tags: xslt

Hi I have seen solutions to do multi-insert text and chars, but cannot figure out how to insert nodes as well?

I call the same replace funtion for every replacement type, save the result in a variable between calls. The result after the first call is a tree fragment and hence the next calls only work on the text part and skip the inserted nodes I just added, so only the last replacement takes effect. So how can I force the replacement function to act on the tree fragment as if it was all just plain text? I use Xslt V2.

source text

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="file:///C:/projects/LOLA/Indesign/8-9069-32-010-3_IndesignPD/Stories/Untitled8.xsl" ?>
  <file>
    <Content>Em dash—</Content>
    <Content>En dash–</Content>
    <Content>discretionary hyphen­</Content>
    <Content>nonbreaking hyphen‑</Content>
    <Content>READ THESE INSTRUCTIONS &amp; THE</Content>
    <Content>Tabs   times 2</Content>
  </file>
```

The XSL

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:my="my:my">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template name="Content">
    <xsl:variable name="temp1">
      <xsl:call-template name="replace">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="." />
        <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'&#173;'" />
        <xsl:with-param name="by">
          <xsl:value-of select="'&#172;'" />
        </xsl:with-param>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- replace any ampersand characters-->
    <xsl:variable name="temp2">
      <xsl:call-template name="replace">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$temp1" />
        <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'&#38;'" />
        <xsl:with-param name="by">
          <![CDATA[&amp;]]>
        </xsl:with-param>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!--  horizontal tab -->
    <xsl:variable name="temp3">
      <xsl:call-template name="replace">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$temp2" />
        <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'&#x9;'" />
        <xsl:with-param name="by">
          <xsl:value-of select="'&#8594;'" />
        </xsl:with-param>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="$temp3" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="replace">
    <xsl:param name="text" />
    <xsl:param name="replace" />
    <xsl:param name="by" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
        <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="substring-before($text,$replace)" />
        <xsl:element name="replaced_text">
          <xsl:element name="font">
            <xsl:attribute name="color">red</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="$by" />
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:call-template name="replace">
          <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$replace)" />
          <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace" />
          <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$text" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What i get

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 Em dash—
 En dash–
 discretionary hyphen­
 nonbreaking hyphen‑
 READ THESE INSTRUCTIONS &amp; THE
 Tabs    times 2
```

What I really wanted:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 Em dash—
 En dash–
 discretionary hyphen<font color="red">¬</font>
 nonbreaking hyphen‑
 READ THESE INSTRUCTIONS &amp; THE
 Tabs <font color="red">→</font> <font color="red">→</font>times 2
```

Comment: "*I use Xslt V2.*" Are you sure about this? Your stylesheet is tagged as version 1.0, you speak of a "tree fragment" which does not exist in XSLT 2.0, and you use a named template where in XSLT 2.0 one would use the `replace()` function.

Comment: Hi Yes its xslt2 I just made this as an example, to keep it simple. The replace function looks suitable, however I was convinsed that you could not insert nodes with that .like replace($mystring, 'somechar', '<font color="red">otherhchar</font>') but i'll give it a go.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at `xsl:analyze-string`.

Comment: Hi well the replace seems to come at a price. I can replace say an '-' for a '+' but when replacing with nodes and inserting say <font face="arial">+</font> then i need to first escape the < with &lt; and the use DOE to get the output as expected. But then when i need to replace say & and < in the same text to &amp; and &lt; then it seems impossible to preserve both all the way through A sample text could be "foo - bar & foo < bar" that should end up as "foo <font face="arial">+</font> bar &amp; foo &lt; bar"

Comment: "*i need to first escape the < with &lt; and the use DOE to get the output as expected*" You should never need to do that.

Comment: Hi well I see that I get i trouble doing it, but how would you then approach the problem?

Comment: I already suggested using `xsl:analyze-string`. I don't have time now for a more detailed answer.